# How to get the vocab file for Bert tokenizer from TF Hub

Tags: tensorflow, tokenize, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model

I'm trying to use Bert from TensorFlow Hub and build a tokenizer, this is what I'm doing:

```py
>>> import tensorflow_hub as hub
>>> from bert.tokenization import FullTokenizer

>>> BERT_URL = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_zh_L-12_H-768_A-12/1'
>>> bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer(BERT_URL, trainable=False)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1781: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1781: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
```

But now when I check the vocab file in the resolved objects I get an empty tensor

```
>>> bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.shape
TensorShape([])
```

What is the proper way to get this vocab file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FullTokenizer = bert.bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", trainable=False)

vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy() #The vocab file of bert for tokenizer
tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file)
```

You can then tokenize using the tokenizer.

```
tokenizer.tokenize('Where are you going?')
```

['w', '##hee', '##re', 'are', 'you', 'going', '?']

You can also pass other functions into your tokenizer. For example:

```
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case) 
tokenizer.tokenize('Where are you going?')
```

['where', 'are', 'you', 'going', '?']